# Como corrigir um JSON errado?

Tags: python, json

Seguinte, eu estou desenvolvendo um programa em Python que colete os dados de um JSON e o transfira para um arquivo CSV.

Contudo, a rotina do servidor me trás um JSON com a estrutura errada em alguns pontos dela, como nesse caso:

```
...
"Campo": valor,
"Campo": "valor"
},
[
{}
][
{
  "Campo": valor,
  "Campo": {},
...
```

Quando rodo o programa (o qual funciona perfeitamente com arquivos JSON formatado corretamente) com este JSON, ele me retorna o erro:

```
  File "C:\Users\mpolillo\Documents\json-extraction\script\fix_json.py", line 17, in fix_test
    content = json.loads(content)
  File "C:\Users\mpolillo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\mpolillo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\mpolillo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 123944 column 2 (char 3653439)
```

Ou seja, está me avisando a linha onde este erro está. Queria saber se há alguma forma de reescrever esse JSON sem precisar fazê-lo manualmente ou sem precisar fazer com que o Python reescreva tudo na mão e, depois, gravá-lo em um novo arquivo ou em cima dele mesmo.

Comment: Quem gera esses JSON? O que seria `valor` da segunda linha do JSON que postou na pergunta?

Comment: É uma rotina escrita em TypeScript. O `valor` e `campo` são só nomes ilustrativos, porque tem informações do banco os quais não posso colocar. O ponto é que, não posso fazer alterações na rotina, tenho que dar um jeito de arrumar este JSON no próprio programa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fica bem difícil responder uma vez que você não falou nada de **como** quer reescrever o JSON (você só quer reescrevê-lo para que se torne um JSON válido, você quer inserir alguns dados que possam estar faltando ou outra coisa...?) nem se os pontos com estrutura errada seguem sempre o mesmo padrão do seu exemplo.

Com isto dito, eu acho que a melhor solução (com as informações que você disponibilizou) é incluir um bloco `try`-`except` para tratar esse erro como uma exceção. Escreva algo assim:

```
try:
    ...
    content = json.loads(content)
    ...
except JSONDecodeError:
    content = 'JSON mal estruturado...'
except Exception as erro:
    content = f'JSON com erro: {erro}'
```

Se você carregar vários JSONs no seu programa isso vai fazer com que seu script continue a escrever no arquivo CSV mesmo que um dos JSONs apresente algum erro. Espero que te ajude, mas considere fornecer mais informações para que possamos respondê-lo com mais exatidão.

Comment: Desculpe, achei que eu tinha conseguido ser específico. O que eu queria era reescrever este JSON, porém ignorar o erro que eu coloquei acima, ou seja, alguma forma de reescrever esse JSON e remover os `[{}][{` que aparecem a torto e a direito.

Comment: Antes de passar por `json.loads`,  `type(content) == str`, certo? Se sim, já tentou usar `replace()`?

`if '[{}][{' in content:
   content = content.replace('[{}][{', '')`